# Your branch and 'origin/master' have diverged, and have 1 and 1 different commits each, respectively

Tags: git

Помогите пожалуйста. Новичок в пользовании Git-ом. 
Выдает такую вот ошибку.

> On branch master
>   Your branch and 'origin/master' have diverged,
>   and have 1 and 1 different commits each, respectively.
>     (use "git pull" to merge the remote branch into yours)

Как от нее избавиться?

Comment: это не ошибка. это констатация факта. соответственно, «избавляться» не от чего.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
git reset --hard origin/master
```

Только в случае если хочешь потерять все локальные изменения.

Comment: Эта команда просто удалит все локальные изменения, которые ещё не были отправлены на сервер.